Access query string from incoming webhook URL in Zoho Flow
I have a fairly straightforward use case, but cannot find anything conclusive on this subject. How can I simply access the query string of the incoming webhook request in Zoho Flow?
I am attaching the Deal ID to the end of the request like:
https://flow.zoho.com/762439902/flo w/webhook/incoming?zapikey=1001.0dec2d7dd15080c464a13925275f0129.448c23ee219c545c89f5a178456cfc8b&isdebug=false&dealID=${Deals.Deal Id}
My API sends data to Zoho Flow with the dynamic Deal ID in the query string with something like:
https://flow.zoho.com/762439902/flow/webhook/incoming?zapikey=1001.0dec2d7dd15080c464a13925275f0129.448c23ee219c545c89f5a178456cfc8b&isdebug=false&dealID=12345
How do I access this 12345 ID to then pass along to update the deal in my flow as the Entry ID? I can only see how to access ${webhookTrigger.payload} not the actual request information beyond the headers (which you can select in Advanced Settings when you create the webhook).I don't see any way to pass the incoming request info (specifically URL here) to a Custom Function using Deluge either.
